# How to make 1/2 inch thick porkchop brown but tender?

Tags: pork, tenderizing, pork-chops

Cheap porkchop cuts here in the Philippines are only 1/2 inch thick. 
It's so hard to brown them or give them color while frying, but still keep it tender. Everytime it's the right color, it's already tough or chewy. 
I don't brine the porkchops though. Should I? Will brining help given the thickness of the porkchop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double cook them. Have your flat iron on over 2 burners. Lightly oiled. Near smoke point. Sear both sides. for color. Move to second skillet iron with lid. slow fry there. Also every 3/4 inch cut threw the outer fat & just threw the outer inner gristle just under the fat. This helps them to lay flat in cooking. Salt & pepper in skillet once seared. 45 seconds a side to sear at proper heat.     This works like cooking on charcoal in the Philippines. Have your coconut charcoal glowing hot. Sear pork chops. Move to next iron plate. That is hot to cook threw on. Move to next iron plate that is warm to store them on with covers. Just like down town cooking. On a long grill. Some pork in the Philippines comes from older hogs & is ground raised. That I do not know how to cure. Unless you buy your pork from a farm. Or in the city know were a pork house is were you pick out your pig to butcher. Best to go behind the wet markets. Buy a live pig & have butchered there for tender pork.

Comment: Or shop the wet markets at 10 am. Opening time. This gives you a chance to see the size of the pig you are buying your chops from. I have them slice mine when I buy there 1 middle finger thick for best cooking. Of chops & steaks. They will have 1/2 a porker hanging on the hook at that time & custom cut for you.